# Validate Credentials and find UserGroups using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am using c# code in MVC web app to validate a user and find the list of user groups that particular user belongs to and using the below code

```
    try
    {
        List<string> user_groups= new  List<string>(); //save the groups the user belongs to 
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com",model.Email,model.Password))      
        {
            bool valid=ctx.ValidateCredentials(model.Email, model.Password); //validate the user
            if(valid)
            {               
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, model.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    // get the user's groups
                    var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                    foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
                    {
                        // save those groups to session for further processing after login
                        if ((bool)group.IsSecurityGroup)
                        {
                            user_groups.Add(group.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                _groups = string.Join(",", user_groups);
                ViewBag.Message = _groups;

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error while validating";
            }

            ctx.Dispose();
        }

    }
    catch (PrincipalServerDownException)
    {
        //If  server is down or some exception happends ,
        // ad_verification = false;
        ViewBag.Message = "Error at groups fetching as server is down ";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error at groups fetching as "+ex.Message;
    }
```

I deployed this to server and try to login as user1 and all went well The code validate the user credentials and returned the list  of user groups the user1 belongs to
Now i logged in as user2 on server , then it returned the below error

```
   Error at groups fetching as Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.
```

It looks like i can still login as user1, but for all other users the error is same as above . While testing on local IIS no such problems 
Any known reasons why the above lines is breaking for second user onwards and any suggestions to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which line is throwing the exception, but it might not like that you're using the user's credentials to pull all the data.

If you're running this from a computer that is joined to the same domain (or a trusted domain) then you don't need to put the credentials here:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com"))
```

The `ValidateCredentials()` line will validate the credentials, and everything else will be done with the credentials that the application is running under.

On a side note, you don't need to call `ctx.Dispose()` when `ctx` is the subject of your `using` block. The whole purpose of `using` is that it will call `Dispose()` after it leaves the `using` block. Take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: The error is at line user.GetAuthorizationGroups() 
I am running this from a computer from a different domain as well. Since support needed for some external users as well.